# Unit Root Test interpretation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, data-analysis

I am analyzing data collected hourly over $9$ years (around $80000$ hours) and I have following result for Unit Root Test :

[image]

How can I interpret the data? Can I use the Autoregressive model?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @n.c. many thanks.It is there but no response .Is it that difficult?

Comment: Then you should probably add the link to the same question on stats.stackexchange. I'm not very familiar with unit root test and autoregressive models.